# Monitoring long running threads

Tags: java, multithreading, command-line

I've taken over a Java command line program that opens a zip file of documents and processes those documents using up to 8 threads (one thread per document) to process the documents and loads their data into the database (the instances of the Inserter class). The previous developer didn't code any way to manage those threads and I've been trying to find some performant way to monitor and cleanly shutdown the threads and the threadpool and the timer.

I can monitor the threads in a continuous loop, but that uses up a lot of CPU and just seems wrong. But when I try to run a TimerTask to check the threads it seems to never exit even when all the work is done. As far as I can tell, this should work. What am I doing wrong?

```
/*
NOTES:
timer is a java.util.Timer
pool is a Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
_listUncompressDirectories is a ConcurrentLinkedQueue<List<File>>
inserters is a ConcurrentMap<Integer, Inserter>
tasks is a ConcurrentMap<Integer, Future>
*/
            // Code isolated from its method.
            for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
                if (_listUncompressDirectories.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
                pool.submit(new Inserter());
                inserters.put(i, new Inserter());
                tasks.put(i, pool.submit(inserters.get(i)));
            }
            timer.schedule(new MonitorTask(), 90 * 1000); //delay in milliseconds


/**
 * Thread pool monitor task.
 */
private class MonitorTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (tasks.isEmpty()) {
            applicationShutdown();
        }
        else {
            for (final int i : tasks.keySet()) {
                if (tasks.get(i).isDone()) {
                    tasks.get(i).cancel(true);
                    inserters.remove(i);
                    tasks.remove(i);
                }
            }
            if (tasks.isEmpty()) {
                applicationShutdown();
            }
        }
    }
}
private static void applicationShutdown () {
    pool.shutdownNow();
    timer.cancel();
    timer.purge();
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: The Observer pattern is great for monitoring status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake. The timer code should look like this:

```
timer.schedule(new MonitorTask(), 90 * 1000, 90 * 1000);
```

Delay 90 seconds and rerun every 90 seconds.

What was happening was the applicationShutdown() method was never being called because the timer task only ran once and never checked the threads again so the threadpool just sat there after all the work was done.

Answer (score 0):

```
I can monitor the threads in a continuous loop, but that uses up a lot of CPU 
and just seems wrong.
```

Your idea is not necessarily wrong nor necessarily uses high CPU.  Here is an example that uses low CPU.

```
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            while(<isAppStillRunningBoolean>) {
            try {
                  doOtherThreadsMonitoringAndHouskeeping();
                  Thread.sleep(52);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
            }
        }});
    t.setDeamon(true);
    t.start();
```

Comment: Hopeless polling loop. I'm sorry, but this has to earn a downvote.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, but if it's not clear from my code, I'm using java.util.concurrent.* for my multithreaded application as I would recommend you do as well, if you do much work with threads. The code above is kind of old school.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I left out a frequency argument for the timer. The timer code above should look like this:

timer.schedule(new MonitorTask(), 90 * 1000, 90 * 1000);

Delay 90 seconds and rerun every 90 seconds.

What was happening was pool.shutdownNow() was never being called because the timer task only ran once and never checked the threads again so it just sat there after all the work was done doing nothing.

I'll answer my own question shortly when I'm allowed to.

Comment: @MartinJames   Polling loop?  Look again... it says  while(<isAppStillRunningBoolean>) not  while(true)  and its a deamon thread on top of that.  I'd expect you and any Java developer to understand isAppStillRunningBoolean is set to false elsewhere in the app.